Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid. [Oauth 2.0 authorization server in API Management]
I have configured Oauth 2.0 authorization server in API Management with version v1 and also have Configured an API to use OAuth 2.0 user authorization.
I could get the token after selecting Authotization_code on a developer portal.
When I try to request any API with the generated token I get 401 response

I have five APIs some of API Spec of the API versions are v1 and some has v2 as well as the audiance are different for all the five APIs.
"auth": {
        "audience": [
          "api://**************",
          "9f*****-****-****-****-*******418"
        ],

Do I need to specify client ID and Client secret from the respective audience in authorization server and add callback URl to the respective app(audience) in app registrations->app (which is mentioned in auth->audience)?
I am new to APIM, has anyone faced this issue, how did you fix it?

The access token missing is a base64 encoded value which should be sent with API requests in the form of an Authorization header.
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
I assume you are testing functionality with Postman, Fiddler or similar, but the API is intended to be used by a client application?
You need to obtain the token at runtime in code. Or, for testing you can POST a request to the MS OAuth 2.0 endpoint:
Headers
POST /YOUR_TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token 
HTTP/1.1 Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&scope=api://YOUR_API_ID/.default

You can get the API ID from the Portal in API Management if you don't already have it.
You should receive a response as follows:
{
  "access_token": "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "ext_expires_in": 3600,
  "scope": "api://YOUR_API_ID/.default"
}

Once you have the token, replace XXXXXX... with it as per above and include the Authorization token in your API requests.

Thank you @Architect Jamie I am using v1 not v2 my call back url looks like this https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aad-tenant}/oauth2/token Also I am not testing functionality with Postman, Fiddler or similar. I am only following steps given on the above links in the question.
